# Extract value inside square brackets within another square bracket based on key

Tags: c#, regex

I have a data like below from where I need to extract data by key.

```
string filter=[[LUB,=,COMMERCIAL],AND,[Pgm,=,PRIVATE],AND,[Regn,=,Rasna],AND,[Month,=,06],AND,[Year,=,2018],AND,[Bywhat,=,M]]
```

I checked similar cases and able to get below code only which is not giving results based on key

I have tried

```
Regex.Match(filter, @"\[(.*?)\]")
```

if I gives `Regn`, I need to get `Rasna`

and if I gives `LUB`, it should give `COMMERCIAL` and like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match that single value you could use a positive lookbehind and a negated character class:

```
(?<=\[Regn,=,)[^]\r\n]+(?=\])
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\[Regn,=,)`
- `[^]\r\n]+` Negated character class, match not a `]` or newline (Add what you also would not want to match(
- `(?=\])` Assert what is on the right is a `]`

See a .NET [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%5bRegn%2c%3d%2c%29%5b%5e%5d%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%5c%5d%29&i=%5b%5bLUB%2c%3d%2cCOMMERCIAL%5d%2cAND%2c%5bPgm%2c%3d%2cPRIVATE%5d%2cAND%2c%5bRegn%2c%3d%2cRasna%5d%2cAND%2c%5bMonth%2c%3d%2c06%5d%2cAND%2c%5bYear%2c%3d%2c2018%5d%2cAND%2c%5bBywhat%2c%3d%2cM%5d%5d) or a [C# DEMO](https://ideone.com/D05lpF)

```
string[] strings = { "LUB", "Pgm", "Regn", "Month", "Year", "Bywhat" };

foreach (string s in strings)
{
    string filter = @"[[LUB,=,COMMERCIAL],AND,[Pgm,=,PRIVATE],AND,[Regn,=,Rasna],AND,[Month,=,06],AND,[Year,=,2018],AND,[Bywhat,=,M]]";
    string pattern = string.Format(@"(?<=\[{0},=,)[^]\r\n]+(?=\])", s);
    var m = Regex.Match(filter, pattern);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Result

```
COMMERCIAL
PRIVATE
Rasna
06
2018
M
```

Comment: Simple and concise

Comment: If there is a space between [ and LUB and a space between ',' and COMMERCIAL. tried string pattern = string.Format(@"(?<=\[ {0},=, )[^]\r\n]+(?=\])", "LUB");

Comment: @Liju You might use `(?<=\[ *{0},=, *)[^\s\[][^]\r\n]*(?=\])` See https://rextester.com/MSS65402

Answer (score 2):

Try following :

```
            string filter="[[LUB,=,COMMERCIAL],AND,[Pgm,=,PRIVATE],AND,[Regn,=,Rasna],AND,[Month,=,06],AND,[Year,=,2018],AND,[Bywhat,=,M]]";

            string pattern = @"\[(?'key'\w+),=,(?'value'[^\]]+)";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(filter, pattern);

            foreach (Match match in matches.Cast<Match>())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key : '{0}', Value : '{1}'", match.Groups["key"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = matches.Cast<Match>().GroupBy(x => x.Groups["key"].Value, y => y.Groups["value"].Value)
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```